# Spark/Scala Parse json file contains only primitive values

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jackson

I am trying to parse simple json file contains list of `[[1,"a"],[2,"b"]]` using Spark/Scala or using Scala `Jackson`

When I tried Spark it gives me the below error

```
//simple line of code
spark.read.json(filePath).show
//error
 Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the
referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column
(named _corrupt_record by default). For example:
spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count()
and spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).select("_corrupt_record").show().
Instead, you can cache or save the parsed results and then send the same query.
For example, val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).cache() and then
df.filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count().;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat.buildReader(JsonFileFormat.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$class.buildReaderWithPartitionValues(FileFormat.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.TextBasedFileFormat.buildReaderWithPartitionValues(FileFormat.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD(DataSourceScanExec.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDDs(DataSourceScanExec.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BaseLimitExec$class.inputRDDs(limit.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalLimitExec.inputRDDs(limit.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:723)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:682)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:691)
```

I also tried to use `Jackson` and parse it as case class but it gave me empty list

```
extractJsonFromStr[AppData]("""[[1,"a"],[2,"b"]]""")
case class AppData(apps :List[(Int,String)])
def extractJsonFromStr[T](jsonString: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Try[T] = {
    implicit val formats: DefaultFormats.type = DefaultFormats
    Try {
      parse(jsonString).extract[T]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you have an example to do the same case?

Comment: Andriy, I just attempted your example and the contents of my `/tmp/app_data.json` file are different. The file contains `{"apps":[[1,"a"],[2,"b"]]}` rather than the primitive array specified in the problem description. This defeats the purpose of the exercise: your parser, along with Jackson and Spark, cannot parse the primitive array despite it being valid JSON.

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk The example is different than what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Charlie Flowers Do you have any idea how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoud can you add complete data sample of the json you want to parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the solution to get `Dataset[T]` where T is my case class we can parse this using Jackson (via json4s), GSON, and possibly other parsers (I've only tested these two) by instructing the parser to read a primitive type:

```
scala> import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

scala> import org.json4s._
import org.json4s._

scala> 

scala> val in: Dataset[String] = Seq("""[[1, "a"], [2, "b"]]""").toDS
in: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> case class InputData(id:Int,name:String)

scala> val parsed : Dataset[InputData] = in.map{x => 
     | implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
     | parse(x).extract[Seq[Seq[String]]] // Not a case class!
     | }.flatMap(x => x).map(x => (x.head.toInt,x.tail.head)).toDF("id", "name").as[InputData]

scala> parsed.show(false)
+-----------+-----------------+
|         id|             name|
+-----------+-----------------+
|          1|                a|
|          2|                b|
+-----------+-----------------+
scala> parsed.map(_.id)
+-----------+
|         id|
+-----------+
|          1|
|          2|
+-----------+
```

Note that the data type for the contents of the array is `String` as Spark cannot conceptualize a JSON array of heterogeneous types, so further manipulation may be required to extract `Int` values from your data.

Comment: I updated your answer. It helped me a lot to figure out the problem and how to solve it. Please have a look and update it if you need.